# Can the unsigned char type have padding bits and/or unused values?

Tags: c

All types except bit fields occupy an integral number of "bytes", and sizeof returns that number. An unsigned char **occupies** 1 "byte", so sizeof(unsigned char) always return 1. Right?

But does an unsigned char always **fill** a "byte", or can CHAR_BITS be less than the number of bits in a "byte" or UCHAR_MAX less than (2 to the power of CHAR_BITS) - 1? If an unsigned char can't hold all values that it's number of bits permit it too, how does copying other types with unsigned chars work?

```
int src = -1, dest;
size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof dest; i++) {
  ((unsigned char *) &dest)[i] = ((unsigned char *) &src)[i];
}
```

Comment: Note that all rules are "as far as any C program or user can tell". Supposing you were using hardware with a 9 bit byte, you could (if you wanted to) still write a C implementation on which `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `UCHAR_MAX` is 255. But no other type would be permitted to use the bit that `unsigned char` doesn't use, and `memcmp` must ignore it, and so on. That way, as far as users of your C implementation is concerned bytes are 8 bit, and the 9th bit is an irrelevant detail of the underlying hardware, that your C implementation hides. In effect it's emulation.

Comment: @SteveJessop OK, but if there's no way what so ever for me to know that, then it's of zero interest for me as a programmer?

Comment: It's of interest if you're the programmer writing the C implementation ;-) Or if you have some code that requires an 8 bit byte, and you'd like to run it on 9 bit machines (or vice-versa), it might be nice to know that emulation is legal as far as the standard is concerned. I admit that this is a niche concern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `unsigned char` cannot have padding bits.

> (C99, 6.2.6.2p1) "For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter)."

And yes, `sizeof (unsigned char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

> (C99, 6.5.3.4p3) "When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1."

Comment: Also, signed char cannot have padding bits either (C11 6.2.6.2/2).

Comment: @Lundin nice, they explicitly added the sentence in C11